# xhtml document - Lang options question

Tags: xml, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

What is the difference between the 2 lines shown below?:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">

<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-GB" />
```

If i didn't have the meta tag, what would be the consequence?

Does the meta one affect screen readers and the top one not? I'm a bit confused as to what exactly they do.

Thanks in advance for any help

Best regards

Skip.

Comment: A small nit: unless you also have en-US, en-AU, en-NZ, etc versions, there is no need to tag your pages with en-GB. Depending on the matching used, people requesting documents in english may not find en-GB, which is too specific. See http://www.langtag.net/tag-wisely.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dive Into Accessibility's [Identifying your language page](http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_7_identifying_your_language.html) recommends adding as much as possible to handle as many screen readers as you can, depending on your doctype:

> If you're using any variant of HTML 4,
>   change your  tag to this (use
>   your own language code if not
>   English):
>
> `<html lang="en">`
>
> If you're using any variant of XHTML
>   1.0, change your  tag to this (use your language code in both
>   places):
>
> `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">`
>
> If you're using XHTML 1.1, change your
>    tag to this (again, insert your
>   own language code):
>
> `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">`

The same article also references [ISO 639.2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/englangn.html) to determine what the value of xml:lang should be, although the XML specification references a separate document, [RFC4646 Best Current Practice - Tags For Identifying Languages](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), which seems to indicate your value of "en-GB" is valid.

Google's [Web Authoring Statistics](http://code.google.com/webstats/2005-12/metadata.html) (2005) have the following to say about it:

> Next is the Content-Language value
>   (used on the http-equiv attribute).
>   Almost as many people use this as
>   specify the lang attribute on the html
>   element. In the HTML5 spec currently
>   the http-equiv attribute is only
>   allowed for the one case of setting
>   the character encoding, which can't
>   really be dropped, as the graph above
>   demonstrates. However,
>   http-equiv="Content-Language" is
>   supported by at least one browser, and
>   as we see here, it is widely used —
>   maybe http-equiv should not be removed
>   after all.

Further, a [thread on webproworld](http://www.webproworld.com/graphics-design-discussion-forum/74467-name-language-vs-http-equiv-content-language.html) talks about the difference between using http-equiv=content-language and name=language to describe the language of the document and implies that both are necessary.

Finally, refer to the [HTML Techniques for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/) document at W3C for some more recommendations, specifically [Identifying the Primary Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#identify-primary-lang).

In conclusion it looks like screen readers are looking at lang attributes more than content-language meta information, but most recommendations I've seen advise using meta data anyway. Especially the Google statistics seem pertinent, so perhaps you should leave both in.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one advantage of the `<meta>` version is that you can specify multiple languages, as in `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-GB, fr" />`, for example. Have a look at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/) for a more in-depth examination of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Language` [is non-conforming in XHTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-content-language).

While it does allow you to specify more than one language, you shouldn't do that (it doesn't help anybody). You should use `xml:lang` attributes on specific elements instead, e.g.

```
<p xml:lang="en">Hello <span xml:lang="de">Welt!</span></p>
```

[W3C I18N FAQ](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang#choosing) is also clearly against `<meta>`:

> The HTTP header or meta element information are not relevant here. By extension, **you should specify the text-processing language of the content as a whole by using the `lang` and/or `xml:lang` attributes in the `html` tag**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **meta http-equiv** is only required (if at all) for
HTML documents (not XHTML), because XHTML allows to specify the language using
**xml:lang**.

So, no difference, the second line is just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP/1.0 RFC 1945 says the Content-Language header field represents "the languages of the intended audience".

> The Content-Language entity-header
>   field describes the natural
>   language(s) of the intended audience
>   for the enclosed entity. Note that
>   this may not be equivalent to all the
>   languages used within the entity.

HTML4 and XHTML1.x treat the meta http-equiv tag as the same information embedded in the html document rather than the HTTP header.

On the other hand, xml:lang and the html lang attribute identify the language of the document, or the fragment contained within the element on which the attribute appears.

So, suppose you had a document that was primarily in French for the purpose of teaching French to English speakers, the content-language would be en-GB, en-US (say), while the xml:lang attribute would be fr-FR.

*However*, HTML 5 changes this, and the meta http-equiv="content-language" is considered non-conforming HTML which nevertheless defines the document-wide default language, and only supports a single language so is effectively identical to xml:lang on the html element. I can't say I understand the reasoning behind this change but Daniel Glazman and Ian Hickson discuss it at the thread starting at http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2008Nov/0083.html