# Is the xml:lang attribute required (in addition to the HTML lang attribute) when specifying the language of an XHTML element?

Tags: html, xhtml, internationalization

I've got an XHTML 1.0 Transitional document. Most of the content is in English, hence this is what I've got at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Some elements are in different languages, e.g.

```
<a href="#" lang="es">Español</a>
```

Do I need to add `xml:lang="es"` to elements like these as well, thus duplicating the language information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sending the file with the `text/html` MIME type, you should, because you're trying to use both HTML and XHTML. (Browsers will only look at the `lang`, though.)

If you're using the correct MIME type (`application/xhtml+xml`), on the other hand, only `xml:lang=""` is necessary, if (correctly) pointing out that you're using HTML, with an HTML doctype, you just need `lang=""`.

Comment: Thanks man, I think that makes sense. So the idea is that if the document is parsed by a parser that only understands XML (or at least doesn’t know about the particular semantics of XHTML), it still knows that that element is in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the XHTML 1.0 spec: yes, use both](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_7).

Doesn't say why though.

[Dive Into Accessibility's language page](http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_7_identifying_your_language.html) says the same thing, as mentioned in [Rahul's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764028/xhtml-document-lang-options-question/764160#764160).

Answer (score -1):

The `<html>` element should provide the `lang` and/or `xml:lang` attribute in order to identify the default language of a document.

It enables assistive technologies, such as screen readers, to provide a comfortable reading experience by adapting the pronunciation and accent to the language. It also helps braille translation software, telling it to switch the control codes for accented characters for instance.

**Quick fix adding "lang" and/or "xml:lang" attributes to the "" element.**

Reference: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations

---

Bad HTML Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <title>An English Page</title>
          <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>  
    <body>     
    ...   
    </body>
</html>
```

Good HTML Example A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
          <title>An English Page</title>
          <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>  
    <body>     
    ...   
    </body>
</html>
```

Good HTML Example B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
          <title>An English Page</title>
          <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>  
    <body>     
    ...   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It 100% does. Read the very first statement. That IS the answer including the further statement starting with "Quick fix". Additionally, the examples validate this above answer and explanation.

Comment: It 100% doesn’t. Read the question. You’ve described what should go on the `html` element. The question is asking about what should go on *other* elements when they’re in a different language to the rest of the document.